Change whitelisted ip to static ip
i currently try to change my whitelisted ip which ist dynamically generated into an static ip.
So i can use a single ip to connect to the db and test without having to generate a new ip every time the session expired and without having to list the ip over and over again in my trusted Ips list.
thats the code which i use for generating a new ip adress:
#Get IP for Whitelist
def get_external_ip(x):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    r = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/")
    public_IP = r.content
    return f"#{x} From {hostname} with publicIP {public_IP}."

print('DRIVER:')
rdd1 = get_external_ip(0)
print(rdd1)

thats why i tried so far but does not work:
# Funktion zum Abrufen einer statischen IP-Adresse
def get_static_ip(x):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    static_IP = "172.161.48.227"  # Statische IP-Adresse hier angeben
    return f"#{x} From {hostname} with publicIP {static_IP}."

# IP-Adresse des Treibers anzeigen
print('DRIVER:')
rdd1 = get_static_ip(0)
print(rdd1)

# IP-Adressen der Arbeiter anzeigen
print('WORKERS:')
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(range(1, 4)).map(get_static_ip)
datacoll2 = rdd2.collect()
for row in datacoll2:
    print(row)

resuming in this error:
Error: (-10709, 'Connection failed (RTE:[89013] Socket closed by peer  (10.0.0.8:50354 -> e79bc323--.hana.prod-eu10.hanacloud.ondemand.com:443))')


Are you trying to list the IP addresses of the worker nodes?

i try to achive a static ip since the code will generate everytime the session ends a new ip, which i have to add in our trusted ip list in SAP datasphere

If you want the worker nodes to have static IPs you have to configure these IPs in your cluster manager setup. There is no way you can change the IP of a worker node from within your Spark code.
